# Edit marks flag as helpful but doesn't resolve the problem

Tags: discussion, edits, flags

I was reviewing my downvotes and flags to see if there was stuff that got left behind. Usually I only downvote posts that I feel should be removed. I came across an answer that was still here today: [If / Else GoTo VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957187/if-else-goto-vba-excel/41959058#41959058).

I thought I might not have flagged it, however when I wanted to flag it, it showed that I already raised the "not an answer" flag on it. I went on to examine what happened to my flag, and it was marked as *Helpful*, because of an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41959058/revisions).

Whilst the edit wasn't all to bad, it wasn't adding anything either as the code in this answer has no relevance to the question. Of course this is something that can be marked as *by-design*, however I feel there is a gap here.

Comment: According to the "rules", everything that can be an answer to any question (not necessarily the question asked) counts as an answer (I sadly can't find the meta post anymore where a Mod confirmed that) but can be downvoted if it is a low quality answer. So that flag should have been declined. (I don't agree with these rules, btw ;/) .... just a note that "not an answer" should be used with caution.

Comment: Well I'm aware that the flag shouldn't be overused, however this is not an answer to the question. It takes some knowledge to know that, but besides that it is a low quality answer. To bad I can't raise a VLQ flag on it. Perhaps that would be best to add to already existing answers, as apperently it passed the triage and/or new posts queue

Comment: Whenever you flag a post, you ask *somebody else* to take care of a problem.  That happened, flag handled.  Finding out later that you are not entirely happy about the way they handled is *always* going to happen sooner or later.  The only way to get a 100% satisfaction guarantee is by handling the problem yourself.  The more rep you gain, the more options you have to do so.

Comment: Well its not that it is handled, the flag just got marked helpfull automatically because someone edited the post.

Comment: @Luuklag: If you have to look at the question to figure out if the answer really is an answer, that's the wrong kind of NAA. Those flags are declined as `flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer`.

Comment: Some more guidance: [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/2675154)